# \tab text \tab text out of alignment

Tags: alignment, body

*UPDATED*

I am listing a recipe and using `\tab` to indent and list the volumes, then `\tab` again to list the ingredient.

On a line with a volume in double digits, the second `\tab` is pushed out of alignment. Is there a way I can overcome this, simply? I am using `siunitx` for units.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{chemmacros,siunitx}
\usepackage{float}

%units for mg ML-1 etc
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \DeclareSIUnit\Molar{\textsc{m}}
    \DeclareSIUnit\litre{L}
    \DeclareSIUnit\units{U}
    \DeclareSIUnit\Osm{Osm}
\usepackage{microtype} %stops siunitx units running into margin
\newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

\begin{document}
\subsubsection{cDNA library generation}
SuperScript\texttrademark\ IV Reverse Transcriptase (Invitrogen\texttrademark , 18090010) was used to synthesise cDNA from \SI{150}{\nano\gram} of purified RNA. Reaction mixes were prepared in advance and added in two steps. Reaction mix one: \\
\tab \SI{11}{\micro\litre}  \tab RNA (\SI{150}{\nano\gram}) in nuclease-free water \\
\tab \SI{1}{\micro\litre}   \tab  dNTPs (N0447S, New England Biolabs) \\
\tab \SI{1}{\micro\litre}   \tab  Random hexamers (N8080127, Invitrogen\texttrademark ) \\
The reaction mix was heated to \SI{65}{\degreeCelsius} for 5 minutes then placed on ice. The following was then added as part of reaction mix two:  \\
\tab \SI{4}{\micro\litre}   \tab SuperScript\texttrademark\ IV buffer \\
\tab \SI{1}{\micro\litre}   \tab SuperScript\texttrademark\ IV reverse transcriptase \\
\tab \SI{1}{\micro\litre}   \tab DTT \\
\tab \SI{1}{\micro\litre}   \tab RNaseOUT\texttrademark\ (10777019, Invitrogen\texttrademark ) \\
The samples were then heated to \SI{23}{\degreeCelsius}, \SI{55}{\degreeCelsius}, and \SI{80}{\degreeCelsius} for 10 minutes each. The synthesised cDNA was diluted 1:10 with nuclease-free water and stored at \SI{-80}{\degreeCelsius}.
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Many thanks

Comment: please always post a complete document so we can see the issue and test answers. `\tab` is not defined by default so it is impossible to guess what layout you are seeing..

Comment: Is this using tabto.sty? If so you'll have to show the tab settings. (A `tabular*` environment may be more appropriate )

Comment: Why don't you use automatic alignment mechanisms of LaTeX?